# how to update php version in netbeans 8.1

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8

Good day,

I can't seem to find a way to update my Netbeans PHP version it is currently on v.5.3.9 I need to update it to the latest stable PHP version.

any help please

Comment: What do you mean? NetBeans does not bundle PHP at all...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - no, but it does have a config setting to specify the version you're developing for so that it knows how to correctly syntax highlight the code. This setting is in the project config.

Comment: Furthermore, NetBeans 8.1 does not support the latest stable PHP version. You need an 8.2 beta.

Comment: So what is the latest version for 8.1. if I change it on my project properties it says I am on 5.5 but if I run phpinfo() it says 5.3.9 ?

Comment: If you run `phpinfo()` and get 5.3.9 then that's the version you have because, as I said, NetBeans does not bundle PHP. Just head to [PHP site](http://php.net/) and grab the version you want.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks will do that